# Too Many Arguments If Statement Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep, arguments

I'm trying to use an if statement with `grep` in order to check if a string exists in some files. Now, the `grep` statement work by itself, but when I run it as part of the `if` statement the output is:

```
line 6: [: too many arguments
```

My Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(grep -c "OutOfMemory" /my/path/to/domains/*/*/subdomains/*/logs/*.*) -ne 0 ];    
then
     echo "String found" 

else
     echo "String not found"

fi
```

If tried using a shorter path but it didn't help.

Any suggestion will help.

Thank you,

Comment: use `find` to search file and then find's exec will help you to grep. Then store the result in some variable and use it. Not putting an answer. there are plenty of examples available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `grep -c` does not produce the correct output.

e.g, you could get multiple files:

```
$ grep -c "OutOfMemory" /my/path/to/domains/*/*/subdomains/*/logs/*.*
/my/path/to/domains/a/b/subdomains/c/logs/my.log:1
/my/path/to/domains/a/b/subdomains/c/logs/another.log:2
```

Your `if` statement cannot handle the multiple lines returned by `grep`, so it fails with `too many arguments`.

If you want to see if there is any file containing the string "OutOfMemory", do this instead:

```
if grep -q "OutOfMemory" /my/path/to/domains/*/*/subdomains/*/logs/*.*
then
...
```

Comment: if I understand you correctly, this will exit on first condition violation? Thank you for the quick answer btw.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It will grep all your files and then return an exit code of 0 (true) if the string is found in any of them, or 1 (false) if not found. The if-statement will use this exit code.

Comment: You can add `-m 1` to ensure that `grep` returns after the first match, if your `grep` supports that flag.

Comment: The `-m 1` flag applies to each input file, not across all of them, which means `grep` will still run on each file even if a match is found in the first. I guess it's worth adding anyway as grep will return quicker on each file.